# MySQL connection over SSL with Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, pdo

I have a problem connecting to my database over ssl in a Laravel application. My config is as follows:

```
       'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'sslmode' => 'require',
            'options'   => array(
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false,
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY => '/certs/client-key.pem',
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => '/certs/client-cert.pem',
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => '/certs/ca.pem',
            ),
        ],

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_name
DB_USERNAME=db_user
DB_PASSWORD=xxxx
```

These setting give me the following error on the MySQL server.

```
2018-10-30T09:18:25.403712Z 71 [Note] Access denied for user 'user'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (using password: YES)
```

Through mysql-client it works perfectly from the client server.

```
mysql -u user -p -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --ssl-ca=/certs/ca.pem --ssl-cert=/certs/client-cert.pem --ssl-key=/certs/client-key.pem
```

Output of `\s' command performed on the client while connected with the above command.

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.26-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

Connection id:      16
Current database:   database
Current user:       user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
SSL:            Cipher in use is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Current pager:      stdout
Using outfile:      ''
Using delimiter:    ;
Server:         MySQL
Server version:     5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.10.1 (Ubuntu)
Protocol version:   10
Connection:     167.99.215.179 via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    utf8mb4
Conn.  characterset:    utf8mb4
TCP port:       3306
Uptime:         23 min 29 sec

Threads: 2  Questions: 38  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 135  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 128  Queries per second avg: 0.026
--------------
```

The application runs inside a docker container based on the `php:7.2.11-fpm` image. And is configured with the following php extensions.

`RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath zip pdo_mysql json tokenizer`

MySQL version:

```
Server version: 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.10.1 (Ubuntu)
```

PHP version:

```
PHP 7.2.11 (cli) (built: Oct 16 2018 00:46:29) ( NTS )
```

PDO version:

```
PDO

PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => sqlite, mysql

pdo_mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
Client API version => mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 38fea24f2847fa7519001be390c98ae0acafe387
```

OpenSSL version:

```
openssl

OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
Openssl default config => /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
openssl.cafile => no value => no value
openssl.capath => no value => no value
```

Any thoughts on this? This is keeping me busy for hours...

Comment: did you tried set `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT` to `true`?

Comment: @Egretos This gives the following error. `3 [Note] Bad handshake` the certificate is a self signed.

Comment: What's your PHP version, openSSL version and PDO & PDO MySQL versions? You can check each in `phpinfo();`. Also what is the version of the MySQL server. Please don't comment and update the question. Is your MySQL server configured to handle SSL connections? Also keep in mind that connecting with SSL to the localhost is pointless.

Comment: @emix I've updated the question. MySQL if configured for SSL, I've also added the output of `\s` executed on the client server while connected with mysql-client.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally solved the issue. The config above is actually good. I was working in the docker container directly. For some reason the config kept in cache.

Following commands did not clear the config cache:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```

I noticed this when I created a new user to connect with the database to test something. I rebuild the container with the new config and everything works perfectly now.

Comment: Having similar issues. Just want to ask the path certs/client-key.pem is that a path on the client server? How do i find out what it is for the config?

Answer (score 5):

1. Please check your .env file. This file will be on website root folder.

   ```
   DB_CONNECTION=mysql
   DB_HOST=hostip
   DB_PORT=3306
   DB_DATABASE=database_name
   DB_USERNAME=database_user_name
   DB_PASSWORD=database_password
   ```

2.also update config -> database.php file as:

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'sslmode' => env('DB_SSLMODE', 'prefer'),
        'options'   => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA      => '/home/.../ca-cert.pem',
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT    => '/home/.../cert.pem',
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY     => '/home/.../key.pem'
        ),
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I figured it out what went wrong, you can read it in my answer. Basically, the `cache:clear` `config:cache',... did not clear my env cache. Rebuilding and deploying a new container did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error when running docker build.  I fixed it by adding a check for pdo_mysql.

```
'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array([
   PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false,
   PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY => '/var/www/html/certs/client-key.pem',
   PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => '/var/www/html/certs/client-cert.pem',
   PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => '/var/www/html/certs/ca.pem',
]) : [],
```