# Multiple database in Laravel with a remote database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, ssh, mariadb

I'm doing a PHP Laravel (7.7.1) project with a mariadb database (10.4.12).

Actually, I'm trying to use a remote mariadb database (10.1.44) on a virtual private server under Debian Stretch (9.11) with my local mariadb database (10.4.12) under Macos Catalina (10.15.4).

The problem is that my Laravel project can't access to the remote database, I saw that the best solution is to use a ssh tunnel but no one solution worked for me.

Here is my `.env` file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=name
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=password

DB_CONNECTION_GAME=mysql
DB_HOST_GAME=11.22.3.444
DB_PORT_GAME=3306
DB_DATABASE_GAME=name
DB_USERNAME_GAME=username
DB_PASSWORD_GAME=password
```

Here is my `database.php` file

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'mysqlgame' => [
            'driver' => env('DB_CONNECTION_GAME', 'mysql'),
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL_GAME'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST_GAME', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT_GAME', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_GAME', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_GAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_GAME', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET_GAME', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

Here is my database model

```
class Whitelisted extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'identifier'
    ];

    protected $connection = 'mysqlgame';

    protected $table = 'user_whitelist';
}
```

And finnaly, here is the error code from `Illuminate`

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `user_whitelist`)
```

What is the best solution to have two databases with one local and the other connected to a remote server ?

Thanks !

Comment: Is the 7845 port on the VPS open for incoming traffic from the outside?

Comment: I changed it to 3306 for the outside mariadb database but It changes nothing.

Comment: Why did you expect it to change something? If the port your database is operating on (which is information you should have available through your VPS) is running on 7845 then changing the port will not magically fix any problem. The question is are you able to connect to that port directly or is the VPS blocking connections it doesn't "trust" and if it is can you add your IP to the list of "trusted" IPs that can connect (or just open access to port 7845 for everyone and rely on SSL and account credentials for security)

Comment: I never said that changing the port will magically fix any problem, it's just more logic but anyway. I'm able to connect to this database when logged to the VPS without blocking connections. I will use the port 3306, the port used by default from mariadb on the vps. The question here how to setup the SSL connection to work with Laravel ? I already tryed with ssh tunnel but it doesn't works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53061182/mysql-connection-over-ssl-with-laravel note that an SSH tunnel and an SSL connection are not the same thing. You will still need to unblock the port that you need to connect to on the VPS for this to work.

Comment: They are not the same things yes but I'm just searching a good way to connect my remote database with any solution. The port needed to connect to the VPS is open.