# How to connect DB using SSL in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, ssl

I have tried db connection by add pem cert files and pdo_mysql setup. But always getting below error.

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Laravel config/database.php configured like below.

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'sslmode' => env('DB_SSLMODE', 'prefer'),
    'options'   => array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA      => 'certs/ca-cert.pem',
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false
    ),
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

Comment: Maybe this other post could help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/53061182/7117697

Comment: @KennyHorna Thanks for your answer. But my server won't have any issue clearing cache. I connected another DB without SSL its works fine only getting issue in SSL with pem file option.

Comment: Is your server configured accordingly?

Comment: @JonathanMartins Yes server configured correctly.

Comment: Same DB. I can able to connect via Heidi SQL in SSL option. Only laravel it throws this error.